# Generate signature (hash) of MemberExpression

Tags: c#, lambda

Consider the following MemberExpressions

```
someObject.someMethod(p => p.FirstName)
someObject.someMethod(p => p.Contact.Address.City)
```

I am writing some code that will walk the expression and look at each member to determine if it is decorated with a given attribute or not.  The purpose of this is to generate a "path" like so:

```
p.Contact.Address.City -> "Contact.Address.City"
```

but if it is decorated with an specific attribute, the path would be generated with a different name:

```
...
[BsonElement("Locale")]
public string City {get; set;}
...

p.Contact.Address.City -> "Contact.Address.Locale"
```

*FYI: This is for a small library I am writing for working with MongoDB*

So walking the expression and checking for the attributes is done using reflection.  It isnt terribly slow, but there is room for improvement.

I would like to add some caching to the path resolution (MemberExpression into a string) but I am not sure the best\most efficient way to generate a signature\hash for the MemberExpression.

I tried some things but they actually slowed the code down.  This method needs to be fast enough to generate the hash every time so that it may be used for lookup and obviously must be faster than walking the expression.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
The code is here: https://github.com/bryanmig/MongoFluentUpdater/blob/master/FluentUpdate/FluentUpdater.cs
(I know there is room for improvements but it is an early prototype)

Answer (score 0):

You always want to cache the results of your reflection work as none of the results will change while the code is running (unless your doing a lot of dynamic assembly loading / generation). Can you share the code that is walking through the expression? That might make it easier to see where you need to incorporate the caching.

Comment: I pulled it down and got it compiling locally but I couldn't find any unique identifier for the expression to build a cache with. I tried using memory addresses out of System.Runtime.Interop but I doubt you want to introduce unsafe code and I'm not sure it would have been faster anyway. Maybe you could try dynamically altering the caller with Refletion.Emit once you have the result but really it's too much work... Maybe look for optimizations elsewhere?  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time anyway!